# Black boxes after upgrade from Kubuntu 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 15.04

Hello after upgrading my Kubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 there seems to be some packages missing. Some graphics (like wallpaper, menu-backgrounds, buttons are not shown correctly. THey are simply staying black. This problem is not only in the Plasma5 Desktop but also on the sddm login-manager.

https://www.asap-soft.com/owncloud/index.php/s/T5dKBdd9dNmk8IO

I think there are some packages missing. Can anybody help me out?
I tried some apt-get and dpkg-reconfigure statements and fiddled around for some hours, but without success...

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had the same issue, the only thing I did that worked was:

```
sudo apt-get purge sddm
```

I really think the main issue is `sddm`.

Comment: To do this, you have to boot into the recovery mode, and select "root" to get to the console. Then type "sudo apt-get purge sddm" followed by "sudo reboot".

BUT: This resulted in windows from the previous session showing up, but without the taskbar or the background wallpaper (which was pitch black). It would seem that purging sddm also removed the kdeplasma5 desktop.

Comment: A reboot helped. Things seem to be working fine now.